# Why are L-factors polynomials in $q^{-s}$?

Tags: number-theory, l-functions

I am interested on integrals of "Tate style", say of the form
$$\int_{F^\times} \Phi(a) \kappa(a) |a|^s d^\times a$$

Here, $F$ is a local field, $|\cdot|$ the associated absolute value, $\Phi$ a Schwatz-Bruhat function and $\kappa$ a finite function (i.e. continuous and such that its translates span a finite-dimensional vector space). Is it clear that this function is a rational function in $q^{-s}$? Do we know what it looks like?

Such integrals often appear, and it seems natural to consider subintegrals on $a$'s of fixed valuation. But unlike in Tate's thesis for instance, here $\kappa$ is not really a character, and $\phi$ is not totally invariant, so that I end up with
$$q^{-ns}\int_{O^\times} \Phi(\omega^n a) \kappa(\omega^n a) |a|^s d^\times a$$
but I am not able to evaluate further or sum over $n$.

Comment: Typically the locally-constant property and the behavior as $a \to 0$ makes the given integral into a sum over $q^{-ns}, n >>0$, which converges as a geometric series to a rational function in $q^{-s}$.

Comment: The span of $\kappa$'s translates being finite dimensional it must be spanned by the $\kappa_{n,b}(a)=\int_{\pi^n O} \kappa(a+b+x)dx$, so $\kappa$ is a finite linear combination of $\kappa_{n,b}$, whence it is locally constant and your result follows.